# Writing a small library in Processing

Tags: java, object, processing

I want to do the following and have no real idea how it can be done, maybe someone can help:

I want to write a small library in Processing, which makes object oriented programming concepts available to students. I'll give you a quick example:

In processing I could simply create a point somewhere in a sketch by typing

```
point(30, 30);
point(20, 20);
```

and so on. What I want to achieve is to wrap these functions into my own classes, e.g.

```
class Point {
  float xPos;
  float yPos;

  Point(float x, float y) {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    point(x, y);
  }
}

Point p = new Point(10,10);
```

This may sound stupid, but this way I can use a object oriented approach better.

My question is now the following: Let's say I build some dozen classes like that and want to use them in a library, so that students can simply use

```
import myLibrary:
Point P = new Point(10, 10);
```

How do I do that? I know that there's a tutorial on the official site which shows the creation of a simple library in Eclipse, but I can't use any processing functions in Java, can I? I guess my constructor of the point class wouldn't work because of that.

I appreciate any help

rikojir

Comment: what is point(x,y); in your constructor? also there should be Setter and Getter method in your program in order to access x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that there's a tutorial on the official site which shows the creation of a simple library in Eclipse, but I can't use any processing functions in Java, can I?

Sure you can. Read [this tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/), along with George's answer, for guides on how to do that. Basically, you can use Processing as a Java library, which gives you access to Processing's classes and function in Java. You'd write your library in Java, export it as a `.jar` file, and then add that to your Processing sketch either using George's answer or by dragging the `.jar` file directly onto your Processing editor.

> I guess my constructor of the point class wouldn't work because of that.

You would have to pass in an instance of your Processing sketch to your `Point` constructor and use that to access Processing's function. Something like this:

```
class Point {
  float xPos;
  float yPos;
  PApplet sketch;

  Point(float x, float y, PApplet sketch) {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    this.sketch = sketch;
  }

  void drawMe(){
    sketch.point(xPos, yPos);
  }
}
```

Then in your sketch, you'd use the `this` keyword to pass in a self-reference to the library code:

```
Point p = new Point(10, 10, this);
p.drawMe();
```

You also might consider simply using a separate tab for your `Point` class instead of an entire external library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it to work now. I still have some open questions: Of course I could now start writing a lot of classes with their own methods and getters and setters and so on.
What I'm wondering about is, why I can't declare my variables (e.g. a new Point instance) in the setup function, and use it then in the draw() function which gets called in a loop.

Can anyone explain that to me, or is there a possibility to use variables declared in the setup() function in the draw() function? Otherwise I would have to implement a animation or game loop by myself everytime.

Comment: @rikojir If you **declare** a variable in your `setup()` function, then that variable is only **in scope** inside the `setup()` function. However, if you declare the variable at the top of your sketch and **initialize** it in your `setup()` function, then you can access that variable in your `draw()` function. That's a pretty standard thing to do in Processing. Shameless self-promotion: see the **scope** section of [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) for a more detailed explanation and example code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap your classes a Processing Java library, you should follow the instructions on the [Processing Library Template](https://github.com/processing/processing-library-template) repository.

It's a bit longwinded compared to how you'd normally compile a Java library, but this is the way to go if you plan to use it with Processing's Contribution Manager.

If you only want to do a quick test, keep it offline/manual install, follow the typical java instructions to compiling a .jar. (Eclipse makes this easier).
Keep in mind you'll still need to follow the Processing library setup:

1. If you need to use any symbols in the library name, use underscores (don't use dashes, dots or other symbols)
2. Place the .jar file in the right folder (library name matches .jar file name : `~/Documents/Processing/libraries/YourAwesomeLibrary/library/YourAwesomeLibrary.jar`)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it just crate a jar fie of all your classes but before creating a jar file don't forget to add all your classes into a single package maybe org,after you have created a jar file then you can either add it to your classpath and you may use it.
If you are using ecllipse then look [here](http://www.quadgen.gq/2016/12/how-to-setup-jar-file-in-ellipse-ide.html) how to use your jar file in it.

Comment: Okay, but how do I add my classes to the core functionalitites? I can write them, but I need the core.jar file of Processing for my library to work if I'm not wrong. 
How do I package these two? I would like to use my library in the Processing IDE later if that's possible